# Can I change the emacs fancy-startup-text?

Tags: emacs

i would like to change the emacs fancy-startup-text (the splash screen that shows up, i know how to close it but not how to replace it with my own). idea is to build my own startup page that fetches some things from the web (news items, sport fixtures, word of the day etc) for emacs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [startup hook](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Init-File.html) to do whatever you want after Emacs starts up:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'my-startup-fcn)
(defun my-startup-fcn ()
  "do fancy things"
  (let ((my-buffer (get-buffer-create "my-buffer")))
    (with-current-buffer my-buffer
      ;; this is what you customize
      (insert "some stuff\nmore stuff"))
    (switch-to-buffer my-buffer)))
```

Answer (score 4):

> User Option: **initial-buffer-choice**
>
> This variable, if non-nil, determines a file or buffer for Emacs to display after starting up, instead of the startup screen. If its value is t, Emacs displays the ‘*scratch*’ buffer. If its value is a string, that specifies the name of a file for Emacs to visit.

– [Emacs Manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work I think. I am on v 22.2.1. This is what I have on my .emacs file 

(setq initial-scratch-message "Hello world")
(setq initial-buffer-choice t)

Even though the buffer choice points to opening of the scratch buffer, I still get to see the default startup message. If i put 

(setq inhibit-startup-message t)

then I dont see the default splash screen but the *scratch* buffer also goes blank.

Answer (score 2):

In your `.emacs` file, write code that sets the `initial-scratch-message` variable, which controls the text that appears in the `*scratch*` buffer.