# Change Emacs welcome splash/screen

Tags: emacs

I realized that it has been asked with some weird titles in Stackoverflow. I can not delete this post cause it already has an answer. if you are interested see following:

1. [Can I change the emacs fancy-startup-text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570605/can-i-change-the-emacs-fancy-startup-text)
2. [How to load file into buffer and switch to buffer on start up in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083181/how-to-load-file-into-buffer-and-switch-to-buffer-on-start-up-in-emacs)

Original Question:
I understand that it is possible to remove the Emacs splash screen! (" [Unable to hide welcome screen in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744672/unable-to-hide-welcome-screen-in-emacs) "). How can I change this welcome screen with my own welcome screen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you can use initial-buffer-choice, as documented here:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html

> User Option: initial-buffer-choice
>
> If non-nil, this variable is a string that specifies a file or directory for Emacs to display after starting up, instead of the startup screen.